# Nginx, PHP-FPM with 2 apps in subfoders

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I have 2 apps in 2 different folders.
I want to use the root folder for everything except when there is /SOMENAME as a folder in the url, in such a case i want to point to that folder.

I tried several location / alias blocks but none of them worked (the location was correct but php files were not served only static content)...
see my config below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #disable_symlinks off;
    server_name join.mydomain.com; #allow few domains
    root /www/main;

    #removing the 'index.php'
    location / {
            if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
            }
            index index.html index.php;
    }

    location /SOMENAME/ {
            root /www/somename;
    }

    #######################
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass        unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include             fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param       PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_index       index.php;
        fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a read through [NGINX common pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/). You probably want a try_files and a rewrite to index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two PHP apps, hosted in different document roots, which means that you need two `location ~ \.php$` blocks. Assuming that `SOMENAME` and `somename` are actually the same, you can use something like this:

```
root /www/main;
index index.html index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}

location ^~ /somename {
    root /www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /somename/index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

The `^~` modifier on the `location` directive, make this prefix location take precedence over the regular expression location block above it, so that PHP scripts are processed by the correct location block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The `try_files` directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

Comment: I actually ended up hiring freelance...this is what we came up with :)